# ld: library not found for - Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker

I am trying to link against a 3rd party library using eclipse. I have build the library, and specified where it is on my machine using properties/paths and symbols/libraries. From this menu, I used the gui to select the location of the .a file. However, on running I still receive the error:

```
ld: library not found for -l/path_to_library_that_I_selected...
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this / things to try?

Cheers

Comment: When you added the library, you didn't actually include the `-l`?

Comment: the command is: g++  -o "output"  ./src/output.o   -l/sweetlibrary.a

Comment: Do you actually have sweetlibrary.a located at the root folder (directly under / ) ? Also, the library file name must be prefixed with lib if you need to use it as a library, so its filename should be libsweetlibrary.a.

Comment: Well, you can certainly call it whatever you want on linux too, but then you can't use the -l option, and have to figure out another way in Eclipse to add additional arguments to the linking stage.

Comment: sorry, there was supposed to be a path to sweet library in that command as per question

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to add `-L` (CAPITAL L) flag, to specify the path to your library, like `-L /my/path/to/library` (as I believe it is not installed in a standard location like /usr/local/lib ). `-l` flag is just for the name of the library, not the path. Go to Project Options/C++ linker, then you can add the flags there, under "Libraries" and "Library search path".

A screenshot example:

[image]

Comment: You add a *directory* to be searched with `-L/some/path/dir/`, not a single library file...

Comment: Yes, the libraries inside /some/path/dir/ should then be visible for the linker, including the specific library in question (in case of OS X, you should also specify DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH as an environment variable, but this is another story...) You select the library with the `-l` flag. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: ok, I have done the above but still the same error. command is now    g++ -L/path -o "output"  ./src/output.o   -llibrary.a

Comment: @user3684792, you don't need the `lib` prefix and `.a` suffix for the library, just add it as `sweetlibrary` under `Libraries`, then specify its full path under `Library search path`. See http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html for a brief intro Your command line should probably be: `g++ -L/path -llibrary -o "output" ./src/output.o `

Comment: just try to compile at command line and see if it works, not sure what's going on with your eclipse build

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I see what you meant, updated the answer.

Comment: But it is not a path, but a *directory*

Comment: sill nothing, even when compiling from cl. Very confused as to why this isn't working. It must be something stupid

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, corrected :) But still I don't realize what is the difference between "PATH" and "Directory"? Isn't the PATH just a directory/folder?

Comment: @user3684792, can you post your complete command line, and the location of the library?

Comment: Path may mean a file path (entire file name, like `/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`) or an environment path (like `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).... And Linux don't have folders (only desktop managers may have some) but directories.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ok, I see what you mean, although frankly I use path to specify a directory (and used folder in my previous comment just in case the OP is used with the term)

Comment: ok, very strange - I copied the library into user/local/lib but it still can't find. Must be a problem with the library

Answer (score 2):

Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > C++ Linker > Libraries

Under Library search path (-L) put the path to the folder where your lib file is.
Under Libraries (-l) put the name of the lib file, do not include the "lib" prefix at beginning of file name or the file extension.

Example:
you want to use the lib file "usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.2/lib/libopencv_ml.a"
in Library search path put "usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.2/lib"
in Libraries put "opencv_ml"